# CUDA and Open MP

Tags: multithreading, cuda, openmp, nvidia

I dont have a Fermi at the moment but the targetting platform is tesla/Fermi, the question I want to ask is if Fermi support Open MP like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(N)

for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
{
  int threadID=omp_get_thread_num();
  cudafunctions<<<blocks, threads, 1024, streams[threadID]>>>(input+i*colsizeofinput);
}//where there are N streams created.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, something like that [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234038/cuda-4-0-rc-many-host-threads-per-one-gpu-cudastreamquery-and-cudastreamsync/5244380#5244380).  OpenMP doesn't provide any specific benefit when trying to launch multiple kernels to the same device (beyond what streams provide) and isn't necessary to achieve concurrent execution of kernels, if that is your intent.

A typical use case for OpenMP with CUDA is [to manage multiple devices](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cudaopenmp).

Comment: Well, if I understand streams correctly, then without parallel for I think I have to use nested for-loops with unneccesary syncs of streams (which could hurt performance) to achieve this (the task is to let a limite number of streams to do some analysis on columns of a very large matrix concurrently).

Comment: Worth noting that this approach can only work on CUDA 4 or later. Prior to CUDA 4, contexts were not thread safe and needed to be explicitly migrated via the  context migration API.