# Is pagelocked status visible to all host threads that use the same device?

Tags: cuda

Suppose I have code that looks like this:

```
cudaHostAlloc( (void**)&pagelocked_ptr, size, cudaHostAllocDefault )
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(num_streams)
{ 
  ...
  cudaMemcpyAsync( pagelocked_ptr + offset_thisthread
                 , src
                 , count
                 , kind
                 , stream_thisthread );
  ...
}
```

Note that I explicitly avoided setting the flag `cudaHostAllocPortable` here.  Each thread uses its own stream, and (I believe) implicitly selects the default Cuda device.

According to Cuda by Example Section 11.4,

> pages can appear pinned to a single CPU thread only.  That is, they will remain page-locked if any thread has allocated them as pinned memory, but they will only appear page-locked to the thread that allocated them.

They go on to say that setting `cudaHostAllocPortable` can fix this issue and allow all threads to recognize the allocation as a pinned buffer.  Therefore, my `cudaMemcpyAsync` call above will fail unless I specify `cudaHostAllocPortable` instead of `cudaHostAllocDefault`.

The Cuda C Guide appears to conflict with this information.  My assumption is that the Cuda context keeps track of which regions of host memory are page-locked and can be transferred  to the device without an intermediate staging copy.  According to the current Cuda C Guide [3.2.1](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#initialization) and [3.2.4.1](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#page-locked-host-memory)

> the primary context for this device...is shared among all the host threads of the application.

and

> by default, the benefits of using page-locked memory described above are only available in conjunction with the device that was current when the block was allocated (and with all devices sharing the same unified address space, if any...)

These seem to imply that the page-locked nature of the allocation is known by Cuda calls across different threads, since they're all using device 0, and that calls to `cudaMemcpyAsync()` in all threads will succeed.  In other words, if I'm interpreting correctly, setting `cudaHostAllocPortable` is only necessary when attempting to share page-locked memory between Cuda contexts (eg. when one is switching between GPUs with `cudaSetDevice`, and offloading a chunk of the page-locked allocation to each one).

Is the information in Cuda by Example simply out of date?  Talonmies' reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401145/cuda-and-open-mp) states

> Prior to CUDA 4, contexts were not thread safe and needed to be explicitly migrated via the context migration API.

but I am not sure how this affected the visibility of page-locked status to Cuda calls from different threads.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pagelocked status should be evident to all threads that are using the same context on a particular device.  If you are using the runtime API (as you are here) then there is normally only one context per device per process, so all threads within that process should be sharing the same context on a particular device, and have the same view of any pointers in that context.

One of the functions of the `cudaHostAllocPortable` flag is described in [the CUDA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gb65da58f444e7230d3322b6126bb4902):

> The memory returned by this call will be considered as pinned memory by **all CUDA contexts**, not just the one that performed the allocation.

The implication is that in a multi-context setting or multi-device setting (a context is unique to a particular device), it is necessary to use this flag to get pinned behavior from that pointer in all contexts visible to the process.